# IE8 and ealier would not stop entering non-english(like Korean, Chinese or Japanese) characters using javascript

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, ime

I am working with jquery below.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#myTextBox").keydown(function () {
        return false;
        (Or when keypress) event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

It works fine with English IME mode in IE 6-9, Chrome.
It stops user typing in the textbox.
But it does not work with Korean IME mode in IE 6, 7 and 8.
But it works with IE 9.
I didn't test with Japanese or Chinese, but I think it would be the same.

What I need to do is prevent users writing Korean characters in some text boxes.
Does anyone know why this happen in IE 6-8?

**EDIT**
According to Fresheyeball idea, I've come to this result.

```
var korean = /[\uAC00-\uD7AF\u1100-\u11FF\u3130-\u318F\uA960-\uA97F\uD7B0-\uD7FF\uFFA1-\uFFFF]/g;
var chinese = /[\u4E00-\u62FF\u6300-\u77FF\u7800-\u8CFF\u8D00-\u9FFF]/g;
var japanese = /[\u3040-\u309F\u1B000-\u1B0FF\u30A0-\u30FF\u31F0-\u31FF\u1B000-\u1B0FF]/g;

<!--
// Korean - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hangul
U+AC00-U+D7AF
U+1100-U+11FF
U+3130-U+318F
U+A960-U+A97F
U+D7B0-U+D7FF
U+FFA1-U+FFFF

// Chinese - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CJK_Unified_Ideographs
U+4E00-U+62FF
U+6300-U+77FF
U+7800-U+8CFF
U+8D00-U+9FFF

// Japanese(hiragana) - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hiragana
U+3040-U+309F
U+1B000-U+1B0FF

// Japanese(katakana) - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Katakana
U+30A0-U+30FF
U+31F0-U+31FF
U+1B000-U+1B0FF
-->

$("#Text2").val($("#Text1").val().replace(korean, ""));
```

However, there are still some errors to fix. Because a character in Korean, Japanese or Chinese, it's not the whole character. It still waits for the next character to hit. Alphabet 'A' is just 'A' and it's finished typing. But KJC is a little bit different from those. I think I can fix that problem. Again, many thanks to Fresheyeball.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also create a whitelist of characters and use regex to validate:

```
  $('#myTextBox').keyup(function(){
      val = $(this).val();
      // use regex to determine if all the characters entered so far are valid
      // and remove invalid ones
      val = val.replace(/[\{rangeStart}-\{rangeStop}]/g, '');
      $(this).val(val);
  });
```

Just fyi, I am not great with regex, so my syntax may be off. But in theory you should be able to use regex to test for ranges of ascii sets, and individual ascii characters.

http://www.javascriptkit.com/jsref/regexp.shtml see the section on ascii literals